# Create And Import configuration file

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I wanna To Create some configuration File such as:

Config File:

```
username="your username"
password="your pass"
option 3
option 4
option 5
option 6
```

On the first time of run it will said File : "Config" as been created
with the Property:

after that, the user fill that file
And on the next run it will Get the information from the file.

How I can create in powershell file with Lines(each line is another propery) Or Create File with content of Properties

And how I can do read from file and get the propry

I mean how i can Create by properyies and how I import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

Puting config to file

```
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{"username"="toto";"Pwd"="XXXX";"Option1"="o1"}
$a | Export-Clixml c:\temp\confif.txt
```

Getting config from file :

```
$b = Import-Clixml c:\temp\confif.txt
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me